# Adding a blank row in importhtml query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to import some Spotify stats from a table on a site into Google Sheets.  I was wondering if it's possible to insert a blank row before the total for each artist, and if it's possible to make it bold?  I'm currently using basic queries like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://chartmasters.org/spotify-streaming-numbers-tool/?artist_name=&artist_id=25pbZ2yTnog5SBbk7WyfNn&displayView=Disco", "table", 1),"select Col2,Col1,Col3 offset 1",0)
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].